# Explanation of a number in allocation data in Android studio

Tags: android-studio

I got data from Allocation tracker in Android Studio. Everything is fine, except, I don't understand particular piece of data. Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxL1l.jpg).

What do these numbers that come right after method name and colon mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the line number with-in the method that the allocation happened on.

Comment: Thanks! I checked capture file with this in mind at many lines, and it really looks like it is true.